# Accessing nested data object using ReactJS (so close!)

Tags: reactjs

This is my first time using React and I am having an issue accessing a nested data object.

I want to access the *commute* value under each object. I can access the top level data like *activities.length*. But, when I attempt something like *activities[0].commute* I am unsuccessful.

My goal is to list all activities with their respective *commute* values.

Any help is incredibly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [activities, setActivities] = useState({})


let clientID = "****";
let clientSecret = "****";


const refreshToken = "****";
const callRefresh = `https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&refresh_token=${refreshToken}&grant_type=refresh_token`


const callActivities = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=`

useEffect(() => {
fetch(callRefresh, {
  method: 'POST'
})


.then(res => res.json())
.then(result => getActivities(result.access_token))
}, [callRefresh])


function getActivities(access){
  fetch(callActivities + access)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => setActivities(data), setIsLoading(prev => !prev))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
 }

function showActivities(){
if(isLoading) return <>LOADING</>
if(!isLoading) {
  console.log(activities)
 return activities.length
  }
}

return (
  <div className="App">
 {showActivities()}
</div>
   );
  }

 export default App;
```

Here's the data:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If activities is a list, then the default value needs to be a list.

```
const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
```

Then simply map activities into a list of components.

```
function showActivities() {
  if(isLoading) return <>LOADING</>;

  return (activities || []).map(activity => {
    return <Text>{activity.commute}</Text>;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, windowsill. Unfortunately, this does not work because 'Text' is undefined. ERROR src/App.js Line 40:13: 'Text' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: What? Why would I know how you want to render your activity commute? Use your own rendering logic.

Comment: Try it with `<>{activity.commute}</>`. If there are any errors, paste the error here please.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (activities || []).map is not a function

Comment: So, I am able to access the top level object of the data such as activities.length, but cannot get deeper in the data structure.

Comment: So activities is truthy but it's not a list. What is it? Log data before you call setActivities. Is it a promise?

Answer (score 0):

You will now have access to the nested data objects, listing all activities with their respective commute values.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);


let clientID = "****";
let clientSecret = "****";


const refreshToken = "****";
const callRefresh = `https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&refresh_token=${refreshToken}&grant_type=refresh_token`


const callActivities = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=`

useEffect(() => {
fetch(callRefresh, {
  method: 'POST'
})


.then(res => res.json())
.then(result => getActivities(result.access_token))
}, [callRefresh])


function getActivities(access){
  fetch(callActivities + access)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => setActivities(data), setIsLoading(prev => !prev))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
 }

function showActivities() {
  if(isLoading) return <>LOADING</>;

  return (activities || []).map(activity => {
    return <Text>{activity.commute}</Text>;
  });
}

return (
  <div className="App">
 {showActivities()}
</div>
   );
  }

 export default App;
```

Comment: I deeply apologize because I know you put energy into responding. I made an error; this is for ReactJS, not React Native. I believe I may have selected the React Native tag.

Comment: Thanks, Johan. Unfortunately, this does not work because 'Text' is undefined.

ERROR
src/App.js
  Line 40:13:  'Text' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: @Devvvvv I see. I'm sorry. I do not know how to help you. Can you rate my answer at least for commitment and goodwill? Thank you